# How to check an input type=“file” has a file selected?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, file-io

I am developing an app with HTML, JavaScript and CSS3 with VS2012 (MetroApp)

I need to trigger a verification for enabling or disabling a button after adding a file on my

```
<input type="file"/>
```

so far I have this:

HTML: default.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>myApp</title>
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="content">
        <h1>myApp</h1>

        <br /><br />
        <button id="imageCaptureButton">Take Picture</button>
        <input type="file" id="uploadCaptureInputFile"/><br />
        <button id="uploadCaptureButton">Subir Foto</button>
        <br /><br />

        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

JavaScript: default.js

```
function getDomElements() {
    _uploadCaptureButton    = document.querySelector("#uploadCaptureButton");
    _uploadCaptureInputFile = document.querySelector("#uploadCaptureInputFile");        
}

function wireEventHandlers() {
    _uploadCaptureInputFile.addEventListener("onchange", verifyControls, false);
}


app.onloaded = function () {
    getDomElements();
    wireEventHandlers();

    _uploadCaptureButton.disabled = true;
}


function verifyControls() {
    if ( _uploadCaptureInputFile != "") {
        _uploadCaptureButton.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        _uploadCaptureButton.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

But I can't make it work, it seems that

```
_uploadCaptureInputFile.addEventListener("onchange", verifyControls, false);
```

it doesn't obey, is there a way to assign this event to my inputType for trigger such verification??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When listening with `addEventListener`, you listen for the *change* event which is just `"change"`, not `"onchange"`. Listening for `"onchange"` will never fire because there is never a matching event fired (unless you create a custom one yourself).